# Crear un alert después de realizar acción asíncrona

Tags: javascript, vb.net, alertdialog

Tengo una función en el code behind de una página aspx hecha con Visual Studio que se llama des de javascript así:

```
function cerrar(id) {
    document.getElementById('<%= btnBloquea.ClientID()%>').click();
    alert("Curso " + id + " bloqueado correctamente.");
}
```

El problema radica en qué la función del btnBloquea a veces da error y se redirige a la página de error (ya lo tengo controlado) pero dé o no dé error el `alert` del código javascript SIEMPRE se muestra aunque la función tenga error ya que se ejecuta de forma asíncrona.

La definición del botón:

```
<asp:Button id="btnBloquea" runat="server" OnClick="btnBloquea_Click" CssClass="hidden"/> //CssCLass hidden es simplement un display:none
```

Y de la función en su mínima expresión:

```
Protected Sub btnBloquea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim idEvento As String
    Dim cerrado As Boolean

    idEvento = hdngroupid.Value()
    cerrado = False 

    'Aquí vienen varios cálculos para si realmente se puede o no cerrar.        

    If Not cerrado Then
          'Aquí me voy a una página de error y NO quiero mostrar ningún alert.
    Else
          'Aquí todo ha ido bien y quiero mostrar el alert.
    End If

End Sub
```

Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Cómo puedo realizar un alert al usuario **sólo** si el resultado de la función es correcto?
2. ¿Hay alguna manera de lanzar el alert sólo cuándo el `click()` haya finalizado?
3. ¿Quizá puedo crear un alert des de la función de code behind?

Comment: cuál es la función que da error? `btnBloquea.ClientID()`?  o el `click()`? podrías mostrar su código?

Comment: Hola Miguel, ¿es un form? ¿un postback? muéstranos como defines el elemento y como se realiza el envió de los datos,

Comment: Yo te recomendaría añadir el código de comprobación en el javascript del cliente para ahorrarte todo este roundtrip. Pero si no puedes o no quieres, haz lo siguiente. Lo primero, quita el alert de después del click() porque no está bien que esté allí. Luego, tienes que notificar en el código del servidor, un mensaje de éxito. Por último tienes que recibir esa notificación del servidor en la página, con algún tipo de control.

Comment: @PA. Necesito acceder a código de servidor porqué accedo a Base de Datos por lo que no puedo trasladar la lógica a javascript. Cómo notifico y recibo ese evento?

Comment: Yo uso sockets. Pero seguro que encuentras código ya hecho y más "nativo" en .NET.

Comment: una búsqueda rápida me ha llevado a SIGNALR, no soy programador .NET, por lo que no puedo decirte si es aplicable a tu caso.

Comment: Buf qué va, estoy en código de visual basic 6, y todo lo que he encontrado es aplicado a MVC o .NET 3.5 para arriba....

Comment: pero la pagina es aspx, no sera que usas VB.NET ? porque mencionas y poner el tag de VB6

Comment: Es aspx.vb la pagina

Comment: ok pero eso no es VB6, eso es VB.NET, estas programando en .net

Comment: Disculpa, siempre me lío por qué cada proyecto va a su bola, tienes razón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redireccionar ante un poblema usarias el Response.Redirect(), de esta forma no volvera a la pagina que tiene la funcion cerrar()

Para ejecutar codigo javascript se usa el

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Protected Sub btnBloquea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim idEvento As String
    Dim cerrado As Boolean

    idEvento = hdngroupid.Value()
    cerrado = False 

    'Aquí vienen varios cálculos para si realmente se puede o no cerrar.        

    If Not cerrado Then
          Response.Redirect("Error.aspx")
    Else
        Dim script As String = String.Format("cerrar('{0}');", idEvento)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "cerrar", script, True)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfecto! Me gusta mucho más así que lo que había puesto de: `Response.Write("<s>alert('Curso bloqueado correctamente.');</s>")` dónde s es `script` (si pongo script no me deja publicar comentario)